# USB 3.0 Quick Charge hub w/4+ ports

Tags: usb, hub

I'm looking for a reasonably priced USB hub to use primarily as a charging station.

- entirely USB 3.0 so that it may also function as a modern USB hub
- at least 4 ports total
- at least 2 ports with Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0
- power output sufficient to utilize all Quick Charge ports simultaneously (10W each)

Comment: quick charge doesn't depend on your port it depends on your device

Comment: That's incorrect, @Dhruva.  A charging port or adapter must also implement the Quick Charge protocol (in addition to the device to be charged) in order to charge at the levels and rates specified by the technology.  Otherwise the device will fall back on the standard USB device charging protocol (or to another fast charging protocol which would also need to be implemented by both the adapter and the device).